# How to use the data type char in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im working on a program that allows the user to play tic tac toe against another human player. So far I have created a "board" an a series of options that allow the user to choose where they want to place an "x" or "o". However, my board is a multidimensional array, with the data type char. Whenever I try to edit this array I get an error, also I cannot declare the array prototype in the header file, and then define the values in the cpp file.
My question is: How can I declare this array so Im able to modify it throughout the program? 
Here is what I have so far:

Header

```
class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        void printBoard();
        void firstMove();
        int updateBoard(int m);
    private:
        char board[3][3];
        int userMove;
        int x;
        int y;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Game::Game()
{
board[3][3]= {{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'}}
}

void Game::printBoard()
{
    for(x=0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(y =0; y<3; y++)
        {
            cout << board[x][y] << " " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Game::firstMove()
{   cout << endl;
    cout << "Your move, enter where you want to place an 'x' " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Top right (1)" << endl;
    cout << "Top left (2)" << endl;
    cout << "Center (3)" << endl;
    cout << "Center top (4) " << endl;
    cout << "Center bottom (5)" << endl;
    cout << "Center right (6) " << endl;
    cout << "Center left (7)" << endl;
    cout << "Bottom right (8)" << endl;
    cout << "Bottom left (9)" << endl;
    cin >> userMove;
    updateBoard(userMove);
}

int Game::updateBoard(int m)
{
    switch(userMove)
    case 1:
        board[1][3] = 'x';
        printBoard();

        return 0;
    }
```

Whenever I try to run this I get an error, there probably are other ways of printing out a "board" on the screen but so far this is what I know.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`std::array<std::array<char,3>,3>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of `char board[3][3]`.

Comment: Arrays are 0 based in `C++`, change `board[1][3]` for `board[0][2]`

Answer (score 0):

after some fixes it works now see http://codepad.org/B5YwnSx1
( though i am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        void printBoard();
        void firstMove();
        int updateBoard(int m);
    private:
        char board[3][3];
        int userMove;
        int x;
        int y;


};



Game::Game()
{

char b[3][3]= { {'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'}};
//copy from b to board
for(x=0; x < 3; x++) for(y =0; y<3; y++)board[x][y]=b[x][y];
}
//added main
int main()
{
Game* g = new Game();
g->updateBoard(1);
}

void Game::printBoard()
{

    for(x=0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(y =0; y<3; y++)
        {
            cout << board[x][y] << " " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


}

void Game::firstMove()
{   cout << endl;
    cout << "Your move, enter where you want to place an 'x' " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Top right (1)" << endl;
    cout << "Top left (2)" << endl;
    cout << "Center (3)" << endl;
    cout << "Center top (4) " << endl;
    cout << "Center bottom (5)" << endl;
    cout << "Center right (6) " << endl;
    cout << "Center left (7)" << endl;
    cout << "Bottom right (8)" << endl;
    cout << "Bottom left (9)" << endl;
    cin >> userMove;
    updateBoard(userMove);
}

int Game::updateBoard(int m)
{
    switch(m)  //where is usermove set? why was m not used?(userMove)
case 1:
board[0][2] = 'x';//board[1][3] is out of bounds 0..2
printBoard();

return 0;
}
```